# jQuery Button.click() event is triggered twice

Tags: jquery, function, button, click

I have the following problem with this code:

```
<button id="delete">Remove items</button>

$("#delete").button({
     icons: {
             primary: 'ui-icon-trash'
     }
}).click(function() {
     alert("Clicked");
});
```

If I click this button, the alert show up two times. It's not only with this specific button but with every single button I create.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click events firing multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your current code works, you can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/s4UyH/

You have something outside the example triggering another [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), check for other handlers that are *also* triggering a `click` event on that element.

Comment: You are right! I put an .unbind("click") in front of the .click(). Now it is working properly. I have to search the element that triggers the event a second time...

Thank you very much!

Comment: That sounds more like you were binding the same click event twice. jQuery will queue the bindings so if you bind several click events to the same element, when you click it, they will all fire.

The slight difference would be the click event was fired twice vs the same click event bound to the element twice.

Comment: @user276289 - It's possible that your code in it's entirety is running more than once, make sure it's only included one time in the page.

Comment: Thanks Nick Craver!  That was exactly my problem, I had my code inlined on a jQuery dialog, so it was executed again when the jQuery UI dialog was rendered.

Comment: Thats the correct answer. Many times, doubly loading the same JS file leads to this bug too.

Comment: This isn't a useful answer, or comment, but 99.99999% of the time... it's your fault.

Answer (score 150):

In that case,try the following

```
$('selected').unbind('click').bind('click', function (e) {
  do_something();
});
```

I had the event firing two times initially, when the page get refreshed it fires four times. It was after many fruitless hours before I figured out with a google search.

I must also say that the code initially was working until I started using the JQueryUI accordion widget.

Comment: This variant also works: `$('.element').unbind("click").on('click', function(e) { ... });`

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Also can confirm @RosdiKasim 's comment is correct - that's what I've used.

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for and got it within 5 minutes.. thanks

Answer (score 44):

Strange behaviour which I was experienced also. So for me "return false" did the trick.

```js
$( '#selector' ).on( 'click', function() {
    //code
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! In my case I couldn't unbind or turn off my event handler, but simply returning false worked!

Comment: This worked for me as well but I would like to know why.

Comment: Take a look at Noor's answer.

Comment: This worked for me. Clicks don't get triggered more than once. However, if the click is bound to a checkbox it doesn't get checked on the click event.

Comment: Same happened to me, handling a checkbox click, this answer fixed my issue

Answer (score 19):

If you use

```
$( document ).ready({ })
```

or

```
$(function() { });
```

more than once, the click function will trigger as many times as it is used.

Comment: this fixed mine issue.

Answer (score 17):

you can try this.

```
    $('#id').off().on('click', function() {
        // function body
    });
    $('.class').off().on('click', function() {
        // function body
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

This can as well be triggered by having both `input` and `label` **inside** the element with click listener.

You click on the `label`, which triggers a click event and **as well** another click event on the `input` for the `label`. Both events bubble to your element.

See this pen of a fancy CSS-only toggle: https://codepen.io/stepanh/pen/WaYzzO

Note: This is **not** jQuery specific, native listener is triggered 2x as well as shown in the pen.

Comment: so, what should be the fix for this? this is my scenario

Answer (score 9):

This can be caused for following reasons:

1. You have ***included the script more than once*** in the same html file
2. You have ***added the event listener twice*** (eg: using `onclick` attribute on the element and also with jquery
3. The ***event is bubbled*** up to some parent element. (you may consider using `event.stopPropagation`).
4. If you use `template inheritance` like **`extends`** in `Django`, most probably you have ***included the script in more than one file*** which are combined together by `include` or `extend` template tags
5. If you are using `Django` template, you have ***wrongly placed a `block` inside another***.

So, you should either find them out and remove the duplicate import. It is the best thing to do.

Another solution is to remove all `click` event listeners first in the script like:

```
$("#myId").off().on("click", function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can skip `event.stopPropagation();` if you are sure that the event is not bubbled.

Comment: Thanks for including the obvious #1 in your answer. I can't believe I didn't realize that's what was going on. (facepalm)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and tried everything but it didn't worked. So I used following trick:

```
function do_stuff(e)
{
    if(e){ alert(e); }
}
$("#delete").click(function() {
    do_stuff("Clicked");
});
```

> You check if that parameter isn't null than you do code. So when the function will triggered second time it will show what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#id").off().on("click", function() {

});
```

Worked for me.

```
$("#id").off().on("click", function() {

});
```

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: Why does this work ? I would like to know. I had a download button which would fire one for first click, two time for second click etc...

Answer (score 2):

Just like what Nick is trying to say, something from outside is triggering the event twice. To solve that you should use event.stopPropagation() to prevent the parent element from bubbling.

```
$('button').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Something most have been causing the click be be triggered more than once.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, i was using the change command like this way

**`$(document).on('change', '.select-brand', function () {...my codes...});`**

and then i changed the way to

**$('.select-brand').on('change', function () {...my codes...});**

and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Related to @Stephan's Answer.

In my case, i have both `input` and `label` in my `.click()` listener.

I just replaced the `label` to `div`, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that binding an element.click in a function that happens more than once will queue it so next time you click it, it will trigger as many times as the binding function was executed. Newcomer mistake probably on my end but I hope it helps.  TL,DR:  Make sure you bind all clicks on a setup function that only happens once.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want your button to be a submit button, code it as 
  Remove items
That should solve your problem.
If you do not specify the type for a button element, it will default to a submit button, leading to the problem you identified.

Comment: Sorry - was uploaded strangely.  Just add type="button" inside your button tag and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

### If you're using AngularJS:

If you're using AngularJS and your jQuery click event is **INSIDE THE CONTROLLER**, it will get disturbed by the Angular's framework itself and fire twice. To solve this, move it **out of the controller** and do the following:

```
// Make sure you're using $(document), or else it won't fire.
$(document).on("click", "#myTemplateId #myButtonId", function () {
   console.log("#myButtonId is fired!");
   // Do something else.
});

angular.module("myModuleName")
   .controller("myController", bla bla bla)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility: **2 events are different in "isTrusted" value**.

I just ran into this problem.
After doing a little debug, I found that the 2 events are different in "isTrusted" value.

---

Conditions:

I called `element.click()` in anotherInputBox's "keydown" event handler.
After a keydown, `element` receive a pair of events, which one is "isTrusted:true", another is "isTrusted:false"

According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted), `isTrusted` is used to determine whether the event is user-triggered(true) or programatically-fired(false).

---

Solutions:

a. Handle double fire better and block the second event by state in your use case

b. Choose whether you want user-triggered or programatically-fired

c. Do not use click(). Make the click handler a function, and both call the function from event handler directly

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue got help from my mentor

```
$('#button_id').click($.debounce(250, function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var cur = $(this);
     if ($(cur).hasClass('btn-primary')) {
          //do something
     } else {
          // do something else 
     }
 }));
```

**myIssue** when the button was clicked *hasClass* shows true instantly it become false and else part executed fixed by using **debounce**

Answer (score 0):

Working on an old project.

I found out that when there is a radio input in the element and when the click will select the radio input, the jQuery click will be triggered twick and so it the Js

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as clicking on any point on the page causes twice click event.

I checked the source code and find the cause that the jQuery library was defined twice for the final page!

1. in the master page of the ASP.NET webform project
2. there was a `ScriptManager` definition in the `Application_Start`
   event of `Global.asax` file.