# on-click function JavaScript trigger twice

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I can't figure out why 'onClick' function trigged twice.

My html code:

```
  <div class="form-actions right1">
        <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn default">
            Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn blue">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
```

Script is here:

```
 $("#btnSubmit").on("click",function () {
            debugger;
            alert("Click");
            CreateOfficeTypeManager.SaveOfficeType();

        });
```

Comment: Possible the script being referenced more than once. Check @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070400/jquery-button-click-event-is-triggered-twice

Comment: Perhaps it is not. If it is in a form and you do not want to submit the form, you need to do this: `$("#btnSubmit").on("click",function (e) { e.preventDefault();` which is better done on the form submit event

Comment: This code only triggers once on my system. I think @ThirueswaranRajagopalan is right. You probably have it referenced 2 times

Comment: Maybe by inspecting the `$event` passed into the callback, you can get more info of what is happening. **Debugger is your friend ..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be binding the "click" even twice.

Put a breakpoint in your $("#btnSubmit")...  instruction and see if it goes there **twice**.

Otherwise, try **unbinding** as shown here [button onclick function firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054889/button-onclick-function-firing-twice)

Finally, if you're in a complex environment, there might be other code handling the clicks for you. Try **preventDefault** as suggested in the comments of your question.

Comment: OK but I hope that you at least checked if your script is executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.

```js
 $("#btnSubmit").on("click",function () {
            debugger;
            alert("Click");

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-actions right1">
        <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn default">
            Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn blue">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
```